# import certain arrays from csv file to google spreadsheet - NOT the whole range, but ONLY some cells with 4 digits instead of 1, 1,

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this script for csv data import from Amit's website. For me it just does not work with the 4 digits dimension

```
function importCSVFromGoogleDrive() {

  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("data.csv").next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

}
```

What I'm trying to do is to import only a specific range of the csv file. As far as I understood if you type 1, 1, you would paste all the cells from the spreadsheet (starting from row1, column1). But this way when new data arrives(for example from another subsidiary) it will overwrite the entire spreadsheet. I'm trying to find a way to import(as described in "Sheet.getRange(1,1,1,12) what does the numbers in bracket specify?") only cells from C2 to G8.Maybe it is possible with 4 digits dimension but i'm just not sure how it will look with Amit's script.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** 
To import only a specific range of the csv file. Only cells from C2 to G8

**Given:**

```
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
```

**Then:**

This will produce the array that would have existed at "C2:G8"

```
var C2G8Array=subArray(csvData,2,3,8,7);
```

**Where:**

subArray() is defined below:

```
//iA=inputArray ulrow=upper left row, ulcol=upper left column, lrrow=lower right row, lrcol=lower right column
function subArray(iA,ulrow,ulcol,lrrow,lrcol)
{
  var oA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<iA.length;i++)
  {
    if(i>=ulrow-1 && i<=lrrow-1)
    {
       oA.push(iA[i].slice(ulcol-1,lrcol));
    }
  }
  return oA;
}
```